# Pass Null Value in DateTime Field in soap ui

Tags: xml, soapui

I Want to Pass null value from Soap UI for Datetime Field
 one option is that i should delete the tag .
There is any other way where i can pass null or some other value in date field.

```xml
 <rt6:DateofBirth></rt6:DateofBirth>
```

Answer (score 24):

`<rt6:DateofBirth></rt6:DateofBirth>` is not null, but empty String (not in all languages this is the same), use `xsi:nil="true"`, so

```xml
<rt6:DateofBirth xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
```

Bear in mind that, as [Ali Baraka suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215941/378115), **xsi** namespace can be defined at root tag level as `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, which allows you to remove from regular tags

Comment: I had to use `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. I tried the version the answer has but I received a validation error. This was in SoapUI 4.6.4.

Comment: Are you sure, that you had `/>` a not only `>`? Maybe your schema do not allow nulls for the field...

Comment: Does not seem to work in Soap UI 5.2.1 - I get an error "Attribute not allowed (no wildcards allowed): nil@http://w3.org/2001/...." despite the fact that in the WSDL my DateTime field is marked as nillable="true"

Comment: Can you open new question for that? You should share you XML and it will be solved, I'm sure ;-)

Comment: This tells you where to put the namespace http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/null-values-in-soap-requests/

Answer (score 13):

General answer:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Add this to namespaces on root tag. Then add this property to tag

```
xsi:nil="true"
```

E.g:

```
<vp1:DateofBirth xsi:nil="true"></vp1:DateofBirth>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
<rt6:DateofBirth xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing a high date like 9999-12-31. That worked for me.